# Save output into Varbinary(max) format

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using this SQL statement, I pull locally stored Excel sheet into SQL Server.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET( 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\SampleTestFiles\outputFile.xlsx;HDR=YES', [Sheet1$])
```

And, I get the complete Excel sheet details with multiple rows in output console.

Now, I want to save the Excel file into a database column of datatype `varbinary(max)`.

Please can anyone let me know how to do that?

Comment: `OPENROWSET` as the name suggests is returning a rowset, not a file which can be stored in a `varbinary` column

Comment: The normal use would be to obtain the data from the Excel file and then save it to SQL Server in proper table/row/column format.

Comment: Although I might be wrong :) https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4963/simple-image-import-and-export-using-tsql-for-sql-server/

Comment: three different questions on the same problem - and it is still not clear what your goal is. Once you get the file into a table, what then? How do you intend to access it? And you say "I want to save the .. file" but to do that you write code. Do you REALLY want to write tsql code to do this? Dale has given a link to do that, but you should really think about where this path will take you.

Answer (score 0):

Use application code like C# to read the file and then insert the binary data into your `varbinary` column in the database.